# What's wrong with my code (c++ beginner)?

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, logic

I'm new to coding and taking a beginner c++ class, I am really not sure what is wrong with the code I have.  I have moved things around to no avail.  The program is meant to ask a user for a letter grade and whether its +, -, or no sign (e.g. A+, A-, A).  I have to use a switch and also if statements but I'm unsure where my logic is failing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char sign, letterGrade;
string gradeRange;

cout << "Enter a letter grade: ";
cin >> letterGrade;

cout << "Enter a sign (+ or -) if applicable; otherwise, enter 'x': ";
cin >> sign;

switch (letterGrade) {
case 'A': {
        if (sign == '+' || sign == 'x') {
            gradeRange = "greater than 93%";
        }
        else if (sign == '-') {
            gradeRange = "greater than or equal to 90%, but less than 93%.";
        }
        break;
    }
    case 'B': {
        if (sign == '+') {
            gradeRange = "greater than or equal to 87%, but less than 90%.";
        }
        else if (sign == 'x') {
            gradeRange = "greater than or equal to 83%, but less than 87%.";
        }
        else if (sign == '-') {
            gradeRange = "greater than or equal to 80%, but less than 83%.";
        }
        break;
    }
    case 'C': {
        if (sign == '+') {
            gradeRange = "greater than or equal to 77%, but less than 80%.";
        }
        else if (sign == 'x' || sign == '-') {
            gradeRange = "greater than or equal to 70%, but less than 77%.";
        }
        break;
    }
    case 'D': {
        if (sign == '+' || sign == '-' || sign == 'x') {
            gradeRange = "greater than or equal to 60%, but less than 70%.";
        }
        break;
    }
    case 'F': {
        if (sign == '+' || sign == 'x' || sign == '-') {
            gradeRange = "less than 60%.";
        }
        break;
    }
    default: {
        cout << "Oops, an error occured, please try again.";
    }
cout << "The student's letter grade range is " << gradeRange << endl;

}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: What is the problem with the code anyway?

Comment: Indent your code properly, you'll clearly see what's wrong.

Comment: You have the final `cout`-statement *inside* the switch-block, which means it is skipped by each `break`-statement.

Comment: This question is bound to go become unhappy quite soon (i.e., it most likely gets downvoted). To learn something from it: **always** check **after** reading your input! For example `if (std::cin >> letterGrade) { /* use the value */ } else { /* deal with the input error */ }`.

Comment: You also can clean up your code too by not having it end with 'else-if' statements within your cases for 'A', 'B' and 'C'.  You also don't need the 'if' statements for cases 'D' and 'F'.  Try seeing if this adjustment works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the final cout-statement *inside* the switch-block, which means it is skipped by each break-statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char sign, letterGrade;
    string gradeRange;

    cout << "Enter a letter grade: ";
    cin >> letterGrade;

    cout << "Enter a sign (+ or -) if applicable; otherwise, enter 'x': ";
    cin >> sign;

    switch (letterGrade) {
    case 'A': 
            if (sign == '+' || sign == 'x') {
                gradeRange = "greater than 93%";
            }
            else if (sign == '-') {
                gradeRange = "greater than or equal to 90%, but less than 93%.";
            }
            break;

        case 'B': 
            if (sign == '+') {
                gradeRange = "greater than or equal to 87%, but less than 90%.";
            }
            else if (sign == 'x') {
                gradeRange = "greater than or equal to 83%, but less than 87%.";
            }
            else if (sign == '-') {
                gradeRange = "greater than or equal to 80%, but less than 83%.";
            }
            break;

        case 'C': 
            if (sign == '+') {
                gradeRange = "greater than or equal to 77%, but less than 80%.";
            }
            else if (sign == 'x' || sign == '-') {
                gradeRange = "greater than or equal to 70%, but less than 77%.";
            }
            break;

        case 'D': 
            if (sign == '+' || sign == '-' || sign == 'x') {
                gradeRange = "greater than or equal to 60%, but less than 70%.";
            }
            break;

        case 'F': 
            if (sign == '+' || sign == 'x' || sign == '-') {
                gradeRange = "less than 60%.";
            }
            break;

        default: 
            cout << "Oops, an error occured, please try again.";


    }// this is for closing switch 
    cout << "The student's letter grade range is " << gradeRange << endl;
    //u kept the cout statement in switch's block so it wouldn't work
    return 0;
} //this is for closing main
```